# How to configure zend framework 2 with vhost?

Tags: php, virtualhost, apache2.4, zendframework

I followed the tutorial of [zend framework 2](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html), but the following error occurs when I try to view the page of the application .

[image]

I configured vhost like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName zf2-tutorial.local.br
    DocumentRoot "/home/patterson/Documentos/scripts/php/zf2-tutorial/public"
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
    <Directory "/home/patterson/Documentos/scripts/php/zf2-tutorial/public">
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

My /etc/hosts looks like this:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       ubuntu-note
127.0.0.1       zf2-tutorial.local.br

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

I can not understand what is happening, could someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following file:

```
$ cat /etc/apache2/mods-available/rewrite.load
```

The line that enables mod_rewrite was commented. So I uncommented the line.

```
LoadModule rewrite_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Then I ran the following command: 
sudo a2enmod rewrite

I also got in slackware, was just uncomment this line in the httpd.conf file

```
LoadModule rewrite_module lib64/httpd/modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

So it was just restart apache:

```
apachectl restart
```